# Strange symbol while reading bluetooth in android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I'm trying to read data from rfid tag through bluetooth and sometimes it works fine and other times I receive this strange symbol: `�`

Does someone know how to filter it? What is it? Or something?

Comment: It's an **unprintable** (ASCII) character. Possibly, a **null** character. (ASCII Code: **0**)

Comment: Mostly due to a temporary `out of sync` in the connection.

Comment: Why can be this out of sync produced ?

Comment: `Micro-variations in the air density`... No, wait - that was another movie (Alien). Small variations in the power of the smartphone or the connected device, interferences (it's radio signals, after all), ionized particles hitting the antennas, unmatched timings to the nanosecond which cause an avalanche effect...

Comment: ?? Just because the device is low on battery can produce that??

Comment: Maybe the CPU becomes slower or the battery becomes hotter. This could cause a temporary time detuning or cause some cycles to over/underlap. We are all subject to physics, like it or not.

Comment: Thank you, I hope the low battery level to be the problem :-)

Comment: Not necessarily. A combination of the listed factors, plus some other variables. In other words, it's **unpredictable**. It **randomly** happens. To me also.

Comment: I have charged the batteries and it works perfectly again. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try to print `ASCII` value of it. Check which character is represented by this `ASCII` value.